# Javascript - Removing spaces with replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

Using `replace(/\s+/g,"");` removes all spaces.
 
Using `replace(" ","");` removes only the first space.
Why?

Comment: The g == global (also \s includes more than just " ")

Comment: /g it is global search.

Comment: Thanks all for explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one [`replace(/\s+/g,"");`] is a *greedy* Regular Expression search that will find all `\s`'s globally.

The second one [`replace()`] is a string replacement and it replaces only the first match.

Answer (score 2):

Because without the global flag, `replace()` only replaces the first occurrence.

EDIT: Your first function will also replace tabs and newlines (all whitespace), while the second only replaces literal spaces.

Answer (score 1):

you can do sth like this:

```
function replaceAll( text, busca, reemplaza ){

  while (text.toString().indexOf(busca) != -1)

      text = text.toString().replace(busca,reemplaza);

  return text;

}
```